# Алгоритм Хаффмана

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте, по своей ФИО, по алгоритму составил таблицу. Не могу понять, какой бинарный код должен принадлежать каждой букве. Прошу вашей помощи, скрин прикреплю из Excel файла.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: постройте в виде дерева. Нагляднее будет. Для E - 000 ответ. Но это плохо видно. В идеале просто уберите стрелки направлений.

Comment: кстати, вы уверены что у вас начальные вероятности одинаковые?

Comment: ПЕТРОВСКИЙ АЛЕКСЕЙ МИХАЙЛОВИЧ, я без пробелов делал. Сейчас сижу в фотошопе перерисовываю в виде дерева, что-то у меня не так идет...после работы мозги совсем не варят уже. Как получилось для E - 000 ? Я на хабре пример посмотрел с древом, его понял, в своем примере ничего понять не могу))

Comment: если очень грубо - то нужно идти по букве и смотреть, когда оно объединяется и это верхнее - то писать 0, когда снизу - 1. И потом развернуть строку.

Comment: т.е. если ориентироваться на ячейки в Excel получается, что в ячейке R6 - 0, в ячейки X3 - 0, а самый первый ноль берется откуда? Или я не правильно понял?

Comment: а самый первый 0 - это AB1.

Comment: Но у меня же с X3 стрелка указывает на Z1, а она указывает на AB2, а AB2 - это 1. Я остальное все понял, не пойму только, почему в конце 0.
т.е. для буквы И будет R7- 1  X3-0  AB2-0   ( И – 001)

Answer (score 1):

```
R6 – 0,  X3 – 0,  AB2 – 1   (E – 100)
R7 - 1,  X3 - 0,  AB2 - 1   ( И – 101)
P7 - 0,  X4 - 1,  AB2 - 1   (Й – 110)
L9 – 0, T6 - 1, Z3 - 1, AB1 - 0 (О – 0110)
L10 - 1, T6- 1, Z3-1, AB1-0 (В – 0111)
J10 - 0, T5 - 0, Z3 - 1, AB1 - 0 (С – 0100)
J11 – 1, T5 – 0, Z3 – 1, AB1 – 0 (К – 0101)
H11 – 0, V5-1, Z2 – 0, AB1 – 0 (А – 0010)
H12 – 1, V5 – 1, Z2 – 0, AB1 – 0 (Л – 0011)
F12 – 0, N9 – 1, V4 – 0, Z2 – 0, AB1 - 0 (П – 00010)
F13 – 1, N9 – 1, V4 – 0, Z2 – 0, AB1 – 0 (Т – 00011)
D13 – 0, N8 – 0, V4 – 0, Z2 – 0, AB1 – 0 (Р – 00000)
D14 – 1, N8 – 0, V4 – 0, Z2 – 0, AB1 - 0 (М – 00001)
B14 – 0, P8 – 1, X4 – 1, AB2 – 1 (Х – 1110)
B15 – 1, P8 – 1, X4 – 1, AB2 – 1 (Ч – 1111)
```

получилось как-то так